# JMeter - JDBC Database request - sql select statement - I want to remove header - don't want header written to 'result variable name'

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter

JMeter - JDBC Database request - sql select statement - I want to remove header - don't want header written to 'result variable name'

SQL = SELECT max(reg_no) From `my_databaseTable` order by reg_no LIMIT 1

view results tree - JDBC Databasse Request - 'Response Body' appears as;
max(reg_no)
1722338

I want;

1722338

note;
(1) 1722338 is the current max reg_no in my database. Tomorrow it could be 1722339. The actual number is irrelevant except that it is the max
(2) the sql statement does not support the notion of '-N'

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a "Variable name", something like `reg_no`, there is a special input field at the bottom:

[image]

and once your JDBC Request sampler will return a value - you will be able to access it as `${reg_no_1}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required

More information:

- [JDBC Request Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

Comment: many many thanks. That's so kind of you. Everything works beautifly now. Thank you